# getting text after span using PHP Xpath?

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have html like this :

```
<h3><span itemprop="name">ABC</span> XYZ</h3>
```

I used xpath but it only get the text in span tag (ABC) , now i want to get text after span . Ex: I  want to get XYZ

Here is my code :

```
string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($string);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//h3/span[@itemprop='name']/text()" );     
    return $nodelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

And ressult is : ABC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`//h3/span[@itemprop='name']/following-sibling::text()`